# is it possible to change a method body in delphi (override an object method)?

Tags: java, delphi, overriding

i m expert in java i used to override methods of objects in java when declaring it like bellow :

```
    public void main(String[] args){
             ...
         JTextField jtf=new JTextField(){

                @override
                public boolean isEditable(){
                        return false;
                }
           }

    }
```

in delphi is there a way to access methods (function & procedure) and override their main code between the begin end. it may look like this:

```
       type
           TForm1 = class(TForm)
           Button1: TButton;
           Timer1: TTimer;
           SpinEdit1: TSpinEdit;

           procedure number(Sender: Tobject);
    .
    .
    .

     procedure number(Sender: Tobject);
     begin
           SpinEdit1.Button.OnDownClick;
             begin
                  SpinEdit1.Increment:=SpinEdit1.Value*2;
             end;

           SpinEdit1.Button.OnUpClick;
             begin
                  SpinEdit1.Increment:=SpinEdit1.Value div 2;
             end;         
     end;
```

is there a way to override OnUpClick and OnDownClick ? i tried to search but i luck the keywords to find it

Comment: Are you talking about how to assign an event method at runtime ? Your example doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I thought I saw you say that you are new to Delphi.  Have you found out yet how to add code in an event handler (e.g. the handler for when a button is clicked) using the Object Inspector yet?

Comment: @TLama in java this is too helpfull since you can change for only one object a specific method without making all a new class and inheritance there is also beta annotation .

Comment: @MartynA not yet i m trying to migrate from java to delphi . i ll do it right now thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no similar feature in Delphi. You need to derive a sub-class explicitly and override the method there. You can't do it inline the way you demonstrate in Java. And even then, you can only override methods that have been declared as `virtual` or `dynamic`.

But if you want to declare an event handler, you don't need to sub-class. Declare an event handler in the form and attach it to the event. The simplest way to do this is by double clicking the event in the Object Inspector.